# How to read remove some lines from json file using node.js

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I want to extract some comment lines of data from json file and after making those into certain format i need to remove those. I am explaining my json file below.

> test.json:

```
#PATH:/test/
#DEVICES:div1
#TYPE:p1
{
  name:'Raj',
  address: {
     city:'bbsr'
  }
}
```

The above file is one test json file. Here I need to read the lines which includes `#` at beginning and then make them separate object like `const obj ={PATH:'/test/',DEVICES:'div1',TYPE:p1}` and finally remove those 3 line from original test.json file using node.js

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet can be used to solve this problem. It can handle any number of similar comments.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline');
const filepath = '/Users/.../nodeText.json';    // file to read from
const writePath = '/Users/.../nodeFileResult.json'  // file to write to
const inputStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath)
const startLine = 'const obj = {\n';
let content = '';

const readPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const lineReader = readline.createInterface({
        input: inputStream
    });

    inputStream.on('end', () => {
        resolve('end');
    });

    lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
        let resultText = '';
        const replaceDict = {
            '#': '"',
            ':': '": "',
            '\n': '",\n'
        };
        const regexString = /#|:|\n/;
        const re = new RegExp(regexString, 'gim');
        if(line.startsWith('#')) {
            resultText = (line+`\n`).replace(re, (match) => {  // \n to make sure its line end and for regex to work
                return replaceDict[match];
            });
        } else if(line.startsWith('{')) {
            resultText = line.replace('{', `}, \n {`);
        } else {
            resultText = line
        }
        content = content + resultText;
    });
});

readPromise
    .then((resolve) => {
        if(resolve === 'end') {
            content = startLine + content
            fs.writeFile(writePath, 
                content, 
                error => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                    return
                }
            })
        }
})
```